# Showing a Windows context menu for multiple items

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I have an application that lists files, and I allow the user to right-click on a file and my application shows the Windows context menu for the selected file.

I use `SHParseDisplayName` to get a pidl for a filename. Then I bind to the parent object:

```
IntPtr pidlLast = IntPtr.Zero;
SHBindToParent(pidl, typeof(IShellFolder).GUID, out oShellFolder, out pidlLast);
```

After I have the parent I can get build the context menu:

```
IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
IShellFolder shellFolder = (IShellFolder)oShellFolder;
shellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(windowHandle, (uint)pidls.Count, 
        pidls.ToArray(), typeof(IContextMenu).GUID, 0, out result);
```

This works perfectly for 1 item or for items with the same parent, but how do I display a context menu for items with different parents?

Comment: Has anyone every tried to do this before? I can do it as long as the items share the same parent, but how do you invoke a menu with different parent objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, apparently you can use `CDefFolderMenu_Create2` to create a context menu for multiple shell items. You can find some excellent information here:

- [xplorer²] — [Advanced shell context menu](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/08Jul07.htm)