# How to populate context menu for multiple shell items (rather than a single IShellItem)

Tags: shell, winapi, com, windows-shell

I know how add the shell context menu when you have **one** [**IShellItem**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) object. The basic procedure is:

- use [**IShellItem.BindToHandler**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler) to bind to the [**IContextMenu**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu) handler
- [**CreatePopupMenu**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createpopupmenu) to create a popup menu
- use [**IContextMenu.QueryContextMenu**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-querycontextmenu) to populate the popup menu with items

Sample code:

```
//I've right-clicked something that represents one shell item.
//Make a context menu appear appropriate for that item

//Get the IContextMenu handler for this shell item
IContextMenu contextMenu;
HRESULT hr = shellItem.BindToHandler(null, BHID_SFUIObject, IContextMenu, out contextMenu);
OleCheck(hr);

//Create a popup menu
HMENU menu = CreatePopupMenu();
if (menu == 0) ThrowLastError();

//Have the shell IContextMenu stuff things into our hmenu
hr = contextMenu.QueryContextMenu(menu, 0, 1, 0x7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE || CMF_ITEMMENU);
OleCheck(hr);

//Now we can show the context menu
TrackPopupMenu(menu, TPM_LEFTALIGN || TPM_LEFTBUTTON || TPM_RIGHTBUTTON || TPM_RETURNCMD, pos.X, pos.Y, 0, callbackWindow, null);
```

And [viola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola); a shell context menu for the selected [**IShellItem**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) appears:

[image]

### But how to do it for multiple IShellItems

If i select multiple items, my code (by definition) still only understands one shell item:

[image]

How could i handle multiple shells item? The only way I know to have the shell populate a menu is when you have **one** shell item.

How do i ask the shell to create an **IContextMenu**, or populate an HMENU, that is for multiple items at once?

## Bonus

The shell can show a context menu that applies to items from different folders:

[image]

## Bonus Reading

- [Showing a Windows context menu for multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208284/showing-a-windows-context-menu-for-multiple-items)
- [How to display system context menu for multiple files in different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553835/how-to-display-system-context-menu-for-multiple-files-in-different-folders/34564058)
- microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell (10/16/2006) - [Shell Objects with different immediate parents](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/4ItaOlUWoos)
- MSDN: [**CDefFolderMenu_Create2 function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-cdeffoldermenu_create2)
- [Advanced shell context menu](https://www.zabkat.com/blog/08Jul07.htm)

Comment: Items in the same parent IShellFolder or from multiple places in the shell namespace? The same IShellFolder is easy enough, the latter is a pain, especially on < Vista.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [IShellItemArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemarray) interface so, something like that for two items:

```
// get two Shell Items and get their respective absolute PIDLs
CComPtr<IShellItem> item1;
HRCHECK(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\myPath1\\myFile1.myExt1", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item1)));

CComQIPtr<IPersistIDList> idl1(item1);
CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE> spidl1;
HRCHECK(idl1->GetIDList(&spidl1));

CComPtr<IShellItem> item2;
HRCHECK(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\myPath2\\myFile2.myExt2", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item2)));

CComQIPtr<IPersistIDList> idl2(item2);
CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE> spidl2;
HRCHECK(idl2->GetIDList(&spidl2));

// build a Shell Item Array from them
LPCITEMIDLIST list[2];
list[0] = spidl1;
list[1] = spidl2;
CComPtr<IShellItemArray> array;
HRCHECK(SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(2, list, &array));

// get the menu object
CComPtr<IContextMenu> menu;
HRCHECK(array->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&menu)));

// ... etc ...
HMENU hMenu= CreatePopupMenu();
HRCHECK(menu->QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, 0x7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE || CMF_ITEMMENU));
```

Usually, you don't have to create arrays, as in copy-paste or drag-and-drop operations, or context menu open calls (namespace extensions, etc.), an array is present in the clipboard or in the data object that's passed in.

Comment: Can you try it with PIDLs from two different folders? Everything works great; except when the items are from different folders. In that case `IShellItemArray.BindToHandler` for the **IContextMenu** fails with `E_UNSPECIFIED_ERROR`. Two physical files, on the same volume, in nearly the same folder path.

Comment: @IanBoyd - I think the ShellItemArray can't do that as after all this is all Shell/UI stuff and you can't show one unique context menu for two files in different folders, can you? What you can do is for each item gets its parent folder IShellFolder implementation (with ShellItem::GetParentAndItem) and query IContextMenu using IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf with item's relative pidl. So you can get as many IContextMenu implementations as items. The next question is what will you do then?

Comment: If you call IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu on each folder with the same input id and index, you will get multiple menu items with the same id. If you give new position and new id, all menu items will be added. Or you can do the merge by yourself if you know what you really want.

Comment: Windows Explorer will show a context menu if you select items from different folders (think Search Results - added screenshot to question). But did you try it? Does it work for you?

Comment: Absolutely, but in this case, with regards to the Shell/Explorer, I think there's still only one containing IShellFolder, the one implemented by the Search Result feature. The shell always builds a ctx menu using an IShellFolder. Internally, this (custom) shell folder is probably merging things itself, and BTW it can be weird: if you try a .jpg and a .txt in same folder (even using search) and in different folders, results are different, including invoke results: for example my "Open with code" menu item will open the .jpg in the later case. Maybe it's using the deprecatd Shell_MergeMenus mthd

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason you cannot use:

```
shellItem.BindToHandler(null, BHID_SFUIObject, IContextMenu, out contextMenu);
```

to get the [**`IContextMenu`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu) for items from different folders. It's called out in the documentation of [**`BindToHandler`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemarray-bindtohandler):

> **BHID_SFUIObject**
>
> Restricts usage to **[`GetUIObjectOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ec863dbf-8ec9-4952-8912-575125e6dd09)**. Use this handler type only for a flat item array, ***where all items are in the same folder.***<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> *emphasis mine*

But that doesn't stop Windows' own search results, as well as Jam-Software's [UltraSearch](https://www.jam-software.com/ultrasearch/) from doing it:

[image]

[image]

So it must be possible.

But that answers the question with part of the other answer.

Comment: The items are all in the same folder: They're all from the Search Results folder. (The items you see are proxy items that masquerade as the real item. The giveaway is that real items don't have a "Found In" property.)