# How to use 'SHCreateDefaultContextMenu' to display the shell context menu for multiple files from different folders

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I want to create a function which displays the shell context menu for a given file list (as string),
but the files are from **different location** on the shell namespace.
(It is the same the context menu which is shown when you right click selected files in the search results area in *Windows Explorer*)

I saw that the issue was discussed in couple of questions before, but none of them gave a solution:
1. [Showing a Windows context menu for multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208284/showing-a-windows-context-menu-for-multiple-items)
2. [Display file properties dialog for files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549603/display-file-properties-dialog-for-files-in-different-directories)
3. [How to display system context menu for multiple files in different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553835/how-to-display-system-context-menu-for-multiple-files-in-different-folders)

However, I noticed that the comments there are referring to [this blog](https://www.zabkat.com/blog/08Jul07.htm) (2007), it is written by the author of a file manager for windows. (his file manager software defenetly shows that he did it)
He mentions overriding `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf` method and implementing a new `IDataObject` interface.

13 years have been passed since then, so I'm thinking using new functions intorduced in *Windows Vista*:
1. I'm trying to use `SHCreateDefaultContextMenu` instead `CDefFolderMenu_Create2`.
2. Maybe the function `SHCreateDataObject` can be used instead of implementing a new DataObject?

I'm not a COM expert, and I struggle to do those tasks, 
Hope someone will fill the missing blocks.

I have put here my effort.
It is implemented as a dll to make it easier for other to use and share.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#define MIN_SHELL_ID 1
#define MAX_SHELL_ID 30000
extern "C"
{
    HRESULT ProcessCMCommand(LPCONTEXTMENU pCM, UINT idCmdOffset, HWND hWnd);


    // Try to convert pICv1 into IContextMenu2 or IcontextMenu3
    // In case of success, release pICv1.
    HRESULT UpgradeContextMenu(
        LPCONTEXTMENU pICv1, // In: The context menu version 1 to be converted.
        void** ppCMout, // Out: The new context menu (or old one in case
                        // the convertion could not be done)
        int* pcmType) // Out: The version number.
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        // Try to get version 3 first.
        hr = pICv1->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu3, ppCMout);
        if (NOERROR == hr)
        {
            *pcmType = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            hr = pICv1->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu2, ppCMout);
            if (NOERROR == hr)
                *pcmType = 2;
        }

        if (*ppCMout)
        {
            pICv1->Release(); // free version 1
        }
        else { // only version 1 is supported
            *pcmType = 1;
            *ppCMout = pICv1;
            hr = NOERROR;
        }
        return hr;
    }

    // Global ref to the context menu to be used while
    // the window messages are being handled.
    LPCONTEXTMENU2 g_pIContext_v2 = NULL;

    // Handle window messages.
    // The messages: WM_DRAWITEM, WM_MEASUREITEM, WM_INITMENUPOPUP, WM_MENUSELECT
    // should be redirected to this function.
    __declspec(dllexport) void OnWindowMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
    {
        if (g_pIContext_v2 == NULL) // Version 1 is used.
            return;

        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        case WM_MEASUREITEM:
            if (wp)
                break;
        case WM_INITMENUPOPUP:
            g_pIContext_v2->HandleMenuMsg(msg, wp, lp);
            break;
        case WM_MENUSELECT:
            // Get the help text and update the status bar , Not implemented yet.
            break;
        }
    }

    // Shows the shell context menu for the given file list at the given position.
    // * error checking is not implemented here.
    __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT ShowContextMenu(
        HWND hWnd,
        int xPos,
        int yPos,
        wchar_t **fullFileNames, // path + file name
        size_t fullFileNamesSize
    )
    {
        HRESULT hr;

        // absolute pidl of the files.
        LPITEMIDLIST *pidlChilds;
        pidlChilds = new LPITEMIDLIST[fullFileNamesSize];

        // Get the desktop folder.
        LPSHELLFOLDER pDesktop;
        SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);

        size_t pidlChildsSize = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < fullFileNamesSize; i++)
        {
            PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl_absolute;
            UINT attributes;
            hr = SHParseDisplayName(fullFileNames[i], NULL, &pidl_absolute, SFGAO_SYSTEM, (SFGAOF*)&attributes);
            pidlChilds[pidlChildsSize] = pidl_absolute;
            pidlChildsSize++;
        }

        // Probably I need to use the new class in place of the pDesktop arg.  
        DEFCONTEXTMENU dcm =
        {
            hWnd,
            NULL, // contextMenuCB
            NULL, // pidlFolder,
            pDesktop, 
            pidlChildsSize,
            (LPCITEMIDLIST*)pidlChilds,
            NULL, // *punkAssociationInfo
            NULL, // cKeys
            NULL // *aKeys
        };


        IContextMenu *pCMv1 = NULL; // Version 1
        IContextMenu *pCMx = NULL; // Versions 2 or 3

        hr = SHCreateDefaultContextMenu(&dcm, IID_IContextMenu, (void**)&pCMv1);

        int pcmType = 0;

        hr = UpgradeContextMenu(pCMv1, (void**)&pCMx, &pcmType);

        if (pcmType > 1) // pCMv1 was feed inside UpgradeContextMenu function.
        {
            g_pIContext_v2 = (LPCONTEXTMENU2)pCMx;
        }

        HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();


        hr = pCMx->QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, MIN_SHELL_ID, MAX_SHELL_ID, CMF_EXPLORE | CMF_CANRENAME);


        UINT cmdID = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu,
            TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RETURNCMD,
            xPos, yPos, 0, hWnd, 0);


        if (cmdID >= MIN_SHELL_ID && cmdID <= MAX_SHELL_ID)
            ProcessCMCommand(pCMx,
                cmdID - MIN_SHELL_ID,  // offset passed
                hWnd
            );



        // Free resources

        for (size_t i = 0; i < pidlChildsSize; i++)
            CoTaskMemFree(pidlChilds[i]);

        pDesktop->Release();

        pCMx->Release();

        delete[] pidlChilds;

        g_pIContext_v2 = NULL;

        return hr;

    }

    HRESULT ProcessCMCommand(LPCONTEXTMENU pCM, UINT idCmdOffset, HWND hWnd)
    {
        CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX ici;
        ZeroMemory(&ici, sizeof(ici));
        ici.cbSize = sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX);
        ici.hwnd = hWnd;
        ici.fMask = CMIC_MASK_UNICODE;
        ici.lpVerb = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(idCmdOffset);
        ici.lpVerbW = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(idCmdOffset);
        ici.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

        return pCM->InvokeCommand((LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO)&ici);
    }

    /*
    class CIShellFolderSpy : public IShellFolder
    {
    public:
        // constructor
        CIShellFolderSpy(LPSHELLFOLDER sf) {
            sf->AddRef();
            m_iSF = sf;
        }

        ~CIShellFolderSpy() { m_iSF->Release(); }

        // IUnknown methods --------
        STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)() {
            return m_iSF->AddRef();
        }

        STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)() {
            return m_iSF->Release();
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)) {
            return m_iSF->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObject);
        }

        // IShellFolder methods ----

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, BindToObject)(
            PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl,
            IBindCtx *pbc,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppv) {
            return m_iSF->BindToObject(pidl, pbc, riid, ppv);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, BindToStorage)(
            PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl,
            IBindCtx *pbc,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppv) {
            return m_iSF->BindToStorage(pidl, pbc, riid, ppv);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, CompareIDs)(
            LPARAM lParam,
            PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl1,
            PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl2) {
            return m_iSF->CompareIDs(lParam, pidl1, pidl2);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, CreateViewObject)(
            HWND hwndOwner,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppv) {
            return m_iSF->CreateViewObject(hwndOwner, riid, ppv);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, EnumObjects)(
            HWND hwnd,
            SHCONTF grfFlags,
            IEnumIDList **ppenumIDList) {
            return m_iSF->EnumObjects(hwnd, grfFlags, ppenumIDList);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, GetAttributesOf)(
            UINT cidl,
            PCUITEMID_CHILD_ARRAY apidl,
            SFGAOF *rgfInOut) {
            return m_iSF->GetAttributesOf(cidl, apidl, rgfInOut);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, GetDisplayNameOf)(
            PCUITEMID_CHILD pidl,
            SHGDNF uFlags,
            STRRET *pName) {
            return m_iSF->GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, uFlags, pName);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, ParseDisplayName)(
            HWND hwnd,
            IBindCtx *pbc,
            LPWSTR pszDisplayName,
            ULONG *pchEaten,
            PIDLIST_RELATIVE *ppidl,
            ULONG *pdwAttributes
            ) {
            return m_iSF->ParseDisplayName(hwnd,
                pbc,
                pszDisplayName,
                pchEaten,
                ppidl,
                pdwAttributes);
        }

        STDMETHOD_(HRESULT, SetNameOf)(
            HWND hwnd,
            PCUITEMID_CHILD pidl,
            LPCWSTR pszName,
            SHGDNF uFlags,
            PITEMID_CHILD *ppidlOut
            ) {
            return m_iSF->SetNameOf(
                hwnd,
                pidl,
                pszName,
                uFlags,
                ppidlOut);
        }

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetUIObjectOf(
            HWND hwndOwner,
            UINT cidl,
            LPCITEMIDLIST *apidl,
            REFIID riid,
            UINT *rgfReserved,
            void **ppv)
        {
            if (InlineIsEqualGUID(riid, IID_IDataObject))
            {
                // i ignore the pidl array supplied and return the good data object
                return m_pMDObj->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
            }
            else {
                // i've seen IDropTarget requests, let base handle them
                return m_iSF->GetUIObjectOf(hwndOwner, cidl, apidl, riid, rgfReserved, ppv);
            }
        }

    protected:
        LPSHELLFOLDER m_iSF;
        CMultiDataObject* m_pMDObj;

    }; // end of class

    */
}
```

Comment: I don't really think much has changed in this regard. Nikos's blog post is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: SHCreateDefaultContextMenu should work fine (and no need for IContextMenu2/3). What doesn't work? any error code?

Comment: @SimonMourier: I'm struggling with the nitty gritty details of actually doing the first task in the document's walk though ("Spin your own IDataObject instead"). Currently the code does not use that.

Comment: You don't need IDataObject to show the default menu for multiple files. See an example that works for me, very similar to yours: https://pastebin.com/raw/4ku9Ts5R

Comment: @SimonMourier Does that really work? It sets `cidl` to 1 so presumably it'll only be generating a menu for the first PIDL in the array and ignoring the second. Additionally the docs specifically say `apidl` is an array of child PIDLs, so this is relying on undocumented behaviour of the desktop folder.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - yes it works fine. I put 1 because I was doing some last testing :-), but put 2 and it will work with 2 files. The desktop shell folder is happy to use absolute pidls as children pidls (for example GetDisplayNameOf), since it's the root of everything. The official shell documentation is only the tip of the shell iceberg...

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks I will check this (I'm not familiar with ATL yet, looks like I should). As You mentioned it, the code don't use IcontextMenu2/3 and I don't see context menu messages related handling neither, does this code support owner-drawn menu items ("send-to" et al)?

Comment: ATL is just how I used COM and allocations, it has nothing to do with the fact it works. Not sure what you mean by support owner-draw menu items. The menu is filled by the Shell, but created and finally shown by your code, so you can do whatever you want on it.

Comment: @Miro Simon's sample works for me. You can have a try. And do you mean add some your own defined items for extending the default menu items by "support owner-drawn menu items"?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have tried it but it didn't work. I followed Simon's code and I got the wrong context menu which was also not functional. This is my code [https://pastebin.com/raw/JJLx2eAv](https://pastebin.com/raw/JJLx2eAv).  When I select those 2 files in Windows Explorer's search result area I get this context menu (what I want) [https://ibin.co/5Lgf57yrmhkP.jpg](https://ibin.co/5Lgf57yrmhkP.jpg),  but the code produces this context menu (What I get) [https://ibin.co/5Lgg1pC6bkaH.jpg](https://ibin.co/5Lgg1pC6bkaH.jpg) Did you get the right context menu?

Comment: @Miro I mean it works for displaying context menu of **the files are from different locations**. For context menu item (*in Windows Explorer's search result area*) like "Send to", yes, it doesn't work for me. That sample code demonstrates basic default context menus as you already found. If you want to add more menu items based on default ones, like "Send to" you need involve `IDataObject` interface.

Comment: @Miro In addition to last comment. Refer to "[Sample program to demonstrate how a program can display a "Send To" menu and send documents to items thereon.](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/sendto/sendto.c#L203)". I want to confirm that do you need exact the context menu list from *Explorer search* or which specified menu item do you focus on?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for the sample program, I will check this.

Comment: @Miro Does the sample program help?