# Win32 iContextMenu: How to generate context menu for multi-selected items?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to implement explorer context menu for my own Windows application.
I was able to show an appropriate context menu for a single file by following this series of articles:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823
However, I don't think the same approach can be used when multiple files are selected because the implementation is passing a pidl of a single file. 
I tested how it worked in Windows explorer. Selecting multiple files and right-clicking worked correctly; It copied selected files or passed selected files to sendto shortcuts. I'm quite not sure how it is done.
Is it possible to do the same thing with iContextMenu interface or is explorer using some private APIs to achieve this behavior?
Here is the code snippet I'm currently using. This assumes that path stores the containing folder and file stores the target file's base name.

```
    IShellFolder *desktop, *fld;
    HRESULT ret = SHGetDesktopFolder(&desktop);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    DWORD chEaten;
    DWORD dwAttributes;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    ret = desktop->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, const_cast<wchar_t *>(path.c_str()), &chEaten, &pidl, &dwAttributes);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        desktop->Release();
        return 0;
    }
    if (desktop->BindToObject(pidl, NULL, IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&fld) != S_OK)
    {
        desktop->Release();
        return 0;
    }
    ret = fld->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, const_cast<wchar_t *>(file.c_str()), &chEaten, &pidl, &dwAttributes);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        desktop->Release();
        fld->Release();
        return 0;
    }
    const _ITEMIDLIST *child = ILFindLastID(pidl);
    ret = fld->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, &child, IID_IContextMenu, NULL, (void **)&contextMenu);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        desktop->Release();
        fld->Release();
        return 0;
    }
    contextMenu->QueryContextMenu(contextMenuHandle, 0, 101, 0x7fff, CMF_NORMAL);
    contextMenu->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu2, (void **)&g_pcm2);
    contextMenu->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu3, (void **)&g_pcm3);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613374/how-to-use-shcreatedefaultcontextmenu-to-display-the-shell-context-menu-for-mu#comment109002477_61613374 for some discussion on this. In short, it's not supported and would be hard to get it exactly the same as Explorer. Explorer itself uses a kludge to make it work.

Comment: `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()` can retrieve a single `IContextMenu` for an array of multiple file IDs. In your code, you are using it to query a single file. Raymond Chen demonstrates this in [Displaying a property sheet for multiple files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130617-00/?p=4073) (using `IContextMenu` to invoke the `Properties` verb on an array of files)

Comment: It's possible to have the exact result as Explorer w/o using anything private. As a start, try my code here (linked by Jonathan): https://pastebin.com/raw/4ku9Ts5R (replace cm.cidl = 1 by cm.cidl = 2). If you need all menus (Send To, etc.) you'll have to create a fake "virtual" IShellFolder implementation (in memory, no need to register anything) with your selected items as children of this folder, instead of using the desktop one. Just like what the search folder does.