# Open multiple images with default image viewer (Microsoft.Photos.exe)

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, shellexecute

For example, when I select three images in Windows Explorer and press enter the default image viewer opens and I can browse through the images.

This code works fine for one image but I can't browse throught the images:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, PChar('open'), PChar(filename), PChar(''), PChar(path), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I tried it with a semicolon as a filename separator like this:

```
var
  path, filename: string;
  filenames: TStringList;
begin
  path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TPath.GetTempPath);
  filenames := TStringList.Create;
  try
    filenames.Delimiter := ';';
    ForEachSelectedRecordInGrid(
      DragDBGrid1,
      procedure begin
        filename := Trim(ExtractFileName(DateienQDateiname.AsString));
        if (filename <> '') then begin
          filename := path + filename;
          DateienQDatei.SaveToFile(filename);
          filenames.Add(filename);
        end;
      end
    );
    if (filenames.Count > 0) then
      ShellExecute(Handle, PChar('open'), PChar(filenames.DelimitedText), PChar(''), PChar(path), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  finally
    filenames.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The content of filenames.DelimitedText is

> C:\Users\completestranger\AppData\Local\Temp\cat.png;C:\Users\completestranger\AppData\Local\Temp\dog.png;C:\Users\completestranger\AppData\Local\Temp\mouse.png

No luck with that.

Any idea?

Comment: Microsoft.Photos is a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application. Absolute pain to do anything with it from other applications. Better off to directly use a viewer you have more control over for anything beyond viewing a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open multiple files at one time with `ShellExecute/Ex()`. You would have to open them individually, and let the Shell/ImageViewer handle them as it sees fit.

Otherwise, you can obtain an `IContextMenu` interface representing multiple files (ie, get the `IShellFolder` of the parent folder, and then use `IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf()` with an array of relative file `ITEMID`s), and then invoke the `'open'` verb via the `IContextMenu.InvokeCommand()` method.

See:

[Win32 iContextMenu: How to generate context menu for multi-selected items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097616/)

[Displaying a property sheet for multiple files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130617-00/?p=4073)